# Small UIButton on top of larger UIButton

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have a smaller `UIButton` which is on top of a larger `UIButton`.

The problem right now is that if I tap the smaller `UIButton`, it also will trigger the larger `UIButton`. The code I'm using to determine if the buttons were tapped is:

```
if(CGRectContainsPoint(button1.frame, location)) {
}
```

Is there a property of the buttons or some automated way to make the smaller button not effect the larger button?

I know I could alter the code above to say if its within button1's frame and not within button2, but is there another way to do it?

Comment: Are you saying you aren't just using the UIButton's standard target/action way of telling you when they are tapped? If I just drag a smaller button inside of a larger button in Xcode, everything works the way you would hope it does by default. Is the smaller button a subview of the larger button for some reason?

Comment: Correct, I'm using a tap gesture recognizer on a view that contains the buttons. The smaller button is not a subview of the larger button.

Comment: If they are actual UIButtons, why aren't you just using their default behavior to detect taps?

Comment: Because of the way I need to load them and detect taps.

Comment: And why not add the small button as a subview of the larger one?

Answer (score 0):

UIControl (which is the superclass of UIButton) passes itself as the only parameter to its target using the action selector. Make use it, it's there for exactly these cases!

```
[smallButton addTarget:self action:@selector(doStuff:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[bigButton addTarget:self action:@selector(doStuff:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

// ...

- (void) doStuff:(UIButton *)btn
{
    if (btn == smallButton)
    {
        // smaller button was clicked
    }
    else
    {
        // bigger button was clicked
    }
}
```